# Iterative into Recursive

Tags: python

Hi everyone, I'm stuck on an assignment and i want to ask a question.
My aim is finding all possible routes between the starter(start) and target(end) node.
I'm working on this code and its graph:
**Note: Values in dictionary show the neighbours of keys.**

```
import sys
graph={'x1': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3'], 'x2': ['x2', 'x4', 'x5'], 'x3': ['x3', 'x6', 'x8'], 'x4': ['x4', 'x5', 'x7'], 'x5': ['x5', 'x7'], 'x6': ['x6', 'x7', 'x8'], 'x7': ['x7', 'x9'], 'x8': ['x8'], 'x9': ['x9']}

def find_all_paths(graph, start, end, path=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return [path]
    if start not in graph:
        return None
    paths = []
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            try:
                newpaths = find_all_paths(graph, node, end, path)
                for newpath in newpaths:
                    paths.append(newpath)
            except TypeError:
                print("No road")
                sys.exit()
    return paths
```

I want this to be a completely recursive function(there should be no "for" loops).I've tried many things but I failed every time.
Do u have any suggestions ?

Comment: It helps to know what the code is doing. Are you doing dfs?

Comment: Why do you want to do it without any loops? That's bad.

Comment: No for loops? Even this wikipedia [site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) uses a loop in its recursive solution. Why make your life harder? Does your assignment really require you to use no loops? I doubt that.

Comment: My assignment requires a fully recursive function so I must to change these "for" loops into recursive

Comment: I still doubt that. Can you share the actual assignment text that you think says so?

Comment: Sharing the assignment text is forbidden but I can show that part:

"You first need to establish the network then find possible routes between sender and receiver nodes finally choose optimal route among them.To accomplish this task you have to use recursion while constructing the possible routes"

Comment: @Eren That doesn't say anything about not using any loops. You're just told to use recursion. And you **are** using recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use depth first search for navigating safely through the graph. This uses recursion and avoids infinite loops using the `marked` map:

```
marked = {}


def navigate(graph):
    v, *tail = graph
    iterate(v, tail) # recursive for loop replacement


def iterate(v, elements):
    if v is not None:
        if v not in marked:
            dfs(graph, v)
        if len(elements) > 0:
            v, *tail = elements
            iterate(v, tail)


def dfs(graph, v):
    print(v)  # do something with the node
    marked[v] = True
    w, *tail = graph[v]
    iterate_edges(w, graph[v])


def iterate_edges(w, elements):
    if w is not None:
        if w not in marked:
            dfs(graph, w)
        if len(elements) > 0:
            v, *tail = elements
            iterate(v, tail)


graph = {'x1': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3'], 'x2': ['x2', 'x4', 'x5'], 'x3': ['x3', 'x6', 'x8'], 'x4': ['x4', 'x5', 'x7'],
         'x5': ['x5', 'x7'], 'x6': ['x6', 'x7', 'x8'], 'x7': ['x7', 'x9'], 'x8': ['x8'], 'x9': ['x9']}

navigate(graph)
```

To be honest, I prefer an implementation with some loops, because then the code is more readable:

```
marked = {}


def navigate(graph):
    for v in graph:
        if v not in marked:
            dfs(graph, v)


def dfs(graph, v):
    print (v)
    marked[v] = True
    for w in graph[v]:
        if w not in marked:
            dfs(graph, w)


graph = {'x1': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3'], 'x2': ['x2', 'x4', 'x5'], 'x3': ['x3', 'x6', 'x8'], 'x4': ['x4', 'x5', 'x7'],
         'x5': ['x5', 'x7'], 'x6': ['x6', 'x7', 'x8'], 'x7': ['x7', 'x9'], 'x8': ['x8'], 'x9': ['x9']}

navigate(graph)
```

The output of both variants is:

```
x1
x2
x4
x5
x7
x9
x3
x6
x8
```

Comment: @Eren: Beware: I had a bug in the first version of the post which is now corrected

Comment: I'm going to use it
Thx a lot

Comment: @gboffi Many thanks for pointing this out. I have updated the answer.